How to backup data including large objects from Postgres
I'm trying to backup from one database and restore on other database both with the same version(12.9). I have one table with large objects(OID) and when I restore the backup the large objects are missing. I have the OID on the table but when I select the large object with the OID does not exist. No errors are showm just miss the data. I'm using dbeaver to backup and restore.
I tried to use the -O line command but no works.

Please share the exact command that you used, we can now only guess.

If you dump or restore a single table, you have to use the additional option --large-objects (--blobs in old PostgreSQL versions) with pg_dump or pg_restore to also dump or restore the large objects.

pg_dump.exe: illegal option -- large-objects
And I'm trying to dump the database not just a single table.

What version of pg_dump is that? Something prehistoric? And if you dump the whole database (no restriction to specific schemas or tables), large objects will be dumped automatically. Please edit your question and tell us the PostgreSQL version and the exact command line for dump and restore.

Version is 12.9.  Like I said I'm using dbeaver to dump and restore but the command is "pg_dump.exe --verbose --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=username --large-objects --format=c --encoding=UTF-8 --file D:/dump-ins-202409020724 -n "public" ins"

Please edit the question and add the information there. Then I can take it into account. Comments can get deleted any time. Whet you write seems to contradict what you wrote above: --large-objects seems to be a valid option.


Is this illegal option -- large-objects  a copy/paste issue or is there is really a space in the in the parameter? 2) Don't use DBeaver to run the commands, run them directly from the command line.


@LaurenzAlbe --large-objects is not supported by version 12, you need -b

The solution is to use -b on the command line. Increase the backup time from 5 minutes to 38 minutes. We decide to avoid large object and use just TEXT.
